# Need help to develope WCF with SSAS

Tags: wcf

How can expose the cubes data using wcf?

Answer (score 0):

WCF is a communications platform - you can expose any data across it.

What you'll need is two things:

- define your WCF service (the protocols, the service methods etc.)
- implement those WCF service methods, and there, you need to access the SSAS cube in some way

There's no direct or generic way to do this as far as I know - you'll have to roll your own. But yes, it's totally possible - the backend can access any kind of data and put it into messages and send those back to the caller.

But one word of warning: all that WCF transports is raw data - you **cannot** expose any kind of functionality - you cannot expose a SSAS drill-down or anything - all you can do is define service methods ("return all sales for country XY") and simple data-transporting classes (classes with just fields and properties - **no methods**) - to be serialized across the wire to the client.